# Dell VLT (MLAG) and Root Bridge Priority

Tags: spanning-tree, dell

I'm not a network guy...

We'll be deploying some Dell switches configured for VLT soon. From what I understand, this is just Dell's version of MLAG. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that I read in the documentation that a VLT domain should be elected as the root bridge of your network. I am wondering why that is. What are the negative effects, if any, of *not* electing a VLT instance (if there is only one) as the root bridge of your network?

I suppose another question I have is if you have multiple VLT domains in a network, should they have a higher priority for root bridge election than all non-VLT switches in the network? That is, configured with a lower priority value compared to all other switches in the network?

I have a basic understanding of spanning tree convergence process and how it blocks ports to prevent loops, but that's about it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you read, but I suspect you misinterpreted it.

Comment: Also, the _lowest_ priority becomes the root, not the highest priority.

Comment: @RonMaupin Lower priority *value* = higher priority. ;-)

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes. Thank you for that clarification. I suppose I should word thing a bit better.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. This is what I meant.

Comment: @RonTrunk I'm not exactly sure what to take away from your comment...Similar recommendations are made for Cisco. For example, "Where possible, the vPC domain should be the spanning tree root bridge."

Comment: It's basically just to make sure that the higher priority is on the equipment that is more likely to act as the 'core' of the network. In any given network design, your VLT connected switches are likely to be at the core or spine of any simple network of other switches or servers. After all, you would not use VLT on a single switch out at the end of a network branch. The whole point of it is to provide a redundant central trunk for a network. Additionally if it is not the root bridge, it might end up with one part of the VLT setup being isolated via some kind of mistake on another switch.

Comment: In addition (for vPCs, anyway), remember that only the primary device participates in STP.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation @FrameHowitzer.

Comment: @RonTrunk It is the same with Dell's VLT as well.